# How do I create form_for for namespaced nested resources in Rails 3.1.3 and Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am new to Rails and am trying to create an Api for a mobile app. Although the Api will generate json responses, I also need a web interface to create the data. My routes look like this:

```
Appone::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api1 do
    resources :reldates do
      resources :movies
    end
  end
end
```

The release_date model:

```
class Api1::Reldate
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :release_date, :type => Date

  embeds_many :api1_movies
  validates_associated :movie
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :movie
end
```

The Movie Model:

```
class Api1::Movie
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, :type => String
  field :release_type, :type => String
  field :release_number, :type => Integer

  embedded_in :api1_reldate, :inverse_of => :api1_movies
end
```

and the reldate show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Release date:</b>
  <%= @api1_reldate.release_date %>
</p>

<% if @api1_reldate.api1_movies.size > 0 %>
  <h2>Movies</h2>
  <% for api1_movie in @api1_reldate.api1_movies %>
    <h3><%= api1_movie.title %></h3>
    <p><%= api1_movie.release_type %></p>
    <p><%= api1_movie.release_number %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<h2>New Movies</h2>
<% form_for([:api1], :url => { :action => :create ,:id => @reldate.movie}) do |form| %>
  <p><%= f.label :title %> <%= f.text_field :title %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :release_type %> <%= f.text_field :release_type %></p>
  <p><%= f.label :release_number %> <%= f.number_field :release_number %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_api1_reldate_path(@api1_reldate) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', api1_reldates_path %>
```

I am unable to get this to work. I can get the reldate page working but after I click on submit, I get an error like this:

```
undefined method `movie' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #18):

15: <% end %>
16: 
17: <h2>New Movies</h2>
18: <% form_for([:api1], :url => { :action => :create ,:id => @reldate.movie}) do |form| %>
19:   <p><%= f.label :title %> <%= f.text_field :title %></p>
20:   <p><%= f.label :release_type %> <%= f.text_field :release_type %></p>
21:   <p><%= f.label :release_number %> <%= f.number_field :release_number %></p>
```

The movie controller look like this:

```
class Api1::MoviesController < ApplicationController
def create
  @api1_reldate = Api1::Reldate.find(params[:api1_reldate_id])
  @api1_movie = @api1_reldate.api1_movies.create!(params[:api1_movie])
  redirect_to @api1_reldate, :notice => "Movie successfully created!"
end
end
```

How can I get this to work? I have tried every possible solution available, but it keeps failing. 
Also, I am using Ryan Bates [Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving `undefined method 'movie' for nil:NilClass` because you are referencing @reldate.movie and assigning @api1_reldate in the controller.  Pick one.

Also, I'm not sure if mongoid's needs are different, but AR uses an array for namespaced routes and form_for:

From: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

For namespaced routes, like admin_post_url:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

I think you need:

```
form_for [:api1, Movie.new] do
```

Your code example shows that you may want:

```
form_for [:api1, @reldate.movie] do
```

Without seeing the controller, I can't tell if @reldate.movie is a new movie, but I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried the solutions suggested by you but it yet doesn't work. The post is updated with the Movies controller.